# python sorting list by true or false

Tags: list, sorting

I have a list of posts. Each post has a Ture or False value which determines where in the list that post should be. True posts should be at the beginning of the list and false posts should be at the end. How can I sort a list like that? For example:

```
posts[0].value = True
posts[1].value = False
posts[2].value = False
posts[3].value = True
```

should be sorted like this:
post[0], post[3], post[1], post[2]

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
posts.sort(key=lambda x: not x.value)
```

`key` is used to specify a custom function to compare the items in the list. The function switches the `value` because in Python `False` < `True`.

Comment: I just used it, tell us why it's not working. `sorted` creates another list, use the `sort` method on your list to change that one.

Comment: Never mind on that. This does work. For some reason I had done: 
sorted(posts , key....)
I guess I misread it. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is more grouping than sorting, since the first operation is O(n) and the other is O(n*logn);

```
t = (i for i in posts if i.value)
f = (i for i in posts if not i.value)
list(itertools.chain(t, f))
```

Comment: I do believe that this works. I was doing something similar to this at first. However, I wanted to use sorting instead. 
Thanks though